# Is this series convergent? $1 + 1/2 + 1/2 + 1/4 + 1/4 + 1/4 + 1/4 + ...$

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Is this series convergent? How to prove?

$$1 + \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{4} + \frac{1}{4} + \frac{1}{4} + \frac{1}{4} + \frac{1}{8} + ... + \frac{1}{8} \ (8 \times 1/8) + \frac{1}{16} + ...$$

It's equal to $\{1 + 1 + 1 + 1 + ...\}$, when I take the $(n+1)^{th}$ number and $n^{th}$ number, the ratio of them can be $\frac{1}{2}$ or $1$. I don't think this is a convergent series, but what is it?

Thanks!

Comment: What is unclear about this questions? Where did the ratio can be $\frac {1}{2}$ come from? even if it  was $\frac {1}{2}$ it is still obvious that it diverges.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Observe that the $(2^n - 1)$th partial sum is given by $$s_{2^n - 1} = 1 + 2 \cdot \frac 1 2 + 4 \cdot \frac 1 4 + \cdots + 2^{n - 1} \cdot \frac 1 {2^{n - 1}} = \underbrace{1 + 1 + 1 + \cdots + 1}_{n \text{ summands}} = n.$$ Consequently, we have that $\lim_{n \to \infty} s_{2^n - 1} = \lim_{n \to \infty} n = \infty,$ and the series diverges.

Comment: Technically, that's the $(2^{n+1}-1)$th partial sum.

Answer (score 2):

The most direct way to see divergence is by noticing that
$$1+\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{3}+\frac{1}{4}+\cdots\leq 1+\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{2}+\cdots$$
where the series on the right hand side is what you have. Since the LHS diverges as the harmonic series, so must the RHS.

Comment: This is entirely backwards and circular. One shows that the harmonic series diverges by showing that it is bigger than something like your RHS. Your RHS diverges obviously, as the partial sums are simply $1/2+ n/2$. That is an easy limit to take for $n \to \infty$.

Comment: @JensRenders Recall that the integral test is also another way to show the divergence of the harmonic series, so I would have to disagree with your claim that this is a circular argument.

Comment: Then take to heart the part where I say it is entirely backwards. It is already strange to go to any type of test when the divergence follows immediately form the definition. It would only serve as an example for the test.

Comment: And even if you do accept to rely on the integral test for this (which you shouldn't), why not apply it to the RHS? Easier, and it also shows how it is superfluous: you will end up with the same limit I put in my first comment when you do that.

Comment: Typically in introductory calculus classes (especially those designed for non-majors) students will have more trouble writing a formula for the nth partial sum than to directly compare with a familiar series. The OP asked to see an explanation, and I gave him one.

Comment: You gave an explaination that uses 2 convergence tests (or is circular) and claim it is the *most direct* one. While applying the definition is trivial in this case. Sorry but no student has problems with finding the partial sums of $1+1+1+\cdots$. If you want to disagree on this, fine. I just felt it was important to put this as a comment beneath it.

Comment: Sure? When I say "most direct", that's assuming the OP is a (not necessarily strong) student in an introductory calculus class trying to get an idea of how things work. From a pure math perspective where students are taught to not produce circular proofs, you are correct. However, from the perspective of students who don't specialize in proof-based mathematics, my explanation would suffice. This is also me speaking as a teaching assistant for a calc class in a US college - I can assure you that the average student isn't as strong as you think.

Comment: I believe that we both have gotten our points across, and any further discussion would be irrelevant.